# Unable to delete file after HttpActionResult in WebAPI controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an async controller method that does some heavy lifting when called, creates folders, zips files, and combines it into a final archive that is returned to the client via download. The problem is, I need to delete the files when finished but I'm getting an error during the delete:

> The process cannot access the file 'Archive.zip' because it is being used by another process.

I understand the problem, but I can't figure out how to resolve it.

Here's some code snippets:

First, I created a custom filter:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class DeleteFileAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute 
{ 
  public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext filterContext) 
  { 
  // Delete file
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
  HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
  var path = new DirectoryInfo(Library.Utilities.Files.MapPath("~/archives"));
  foreach (var dir in path.GetDirectories())
  {
    dir.Delete(true);
  }
  base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

}

Here's my main controller entry point which I decorated with that custom filter:

```
[DeleteFile]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Download(string boardId, string boardName)
{          
  // I do a bunch of file related stuff, and then:          
  return new FileActionResult(boardName + ".zip", zipPath);
}
```

And here is my `FileActionResult` class:

```
public class FileActionResult : IHttpActionResult
{
  public FileActionResult(string filename, string path)
  {
    Filename = filename;
    Path = path;
  }

  public string Filename { get; }
  public string Path { get; }

  public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage {Content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(Path))};
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-zip-compressed");

    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
      FileName = Filename
    }; 

    return Task.FromResult(response);
  }
}
```

I assumed that by flushing and ending the response within the action filter prior to deleting the files would help, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try disposing of the stream content:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;

    using (var stream = new File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        response = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StreamContent(stream)};

        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-zip-compressed");

        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = Filename
        }; 
    }   

    return Task.FromResult(response);
}
```

Comment: So I realized that in my filter, flushing and ending my response cleared out the attachment so that's another issue. I've incorporated your example (slightly differently) but can't tell if this solves the problem until I figure out my newly found issue.